# ro.custom.build.version is not changing at phone info

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms

I am trying to change ro.custom.build.version but this particular change is not propagated to the resulting build.

Comment: That's rather a development related question, and as such off topic here. I'm not sure if it's valid on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/) (you might need to check their FAQ first).